# Need to fill this face in but it has vertices that prevent it from filling in properly

Tags: mesh, edit-mode, vertices, faces, edges

I'm trying to fill the lower part in (in the first picture), but can't because the vertices (second picture) are blocking it from being filled in properly...

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's not a good idea to fill a face like that in one go anyway. Select pairs of opposing edges and fill it in sections.

Comment: Can you demonstrate how I could do that with a similar model? I can share the .blend file if needed but would rather not...

Comment: I've put an image of an object I knocked up [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lpin3zp63w3s8r7/Snip.jpg?dl=0) which looks to be as close to yours as I can get from your images. I assume you're trying to fill the bottom surface? However I can't really see why you couldn't fill yours as I can just Alt-click the edge of mine to select the whole edge and 'F' to fill. Might be worth selecting All and then M > Merge by distance on yours and trying again in case there are duplicate vertices.